# Persistent Volume Claim binds to wrong volume when pod is moved to another zone

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm struggling with this for a while now. I have a Deployment that has a PVC. This is deployed in EKS, on zone **a**. PV is properly created and all is fine.
But when the pod is moved to a different zone, **b** it fails to spin up and gets stuck in Pending:

> pod didn't trigger scale-up: 5 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector, 1 node(s) had volume node affinity conflict, 1 node(s) had no available volume zone

My PVC is still bound to the zone **a** PV

This is my PVC:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: appName-pvc-ebs
  namespace: appName-namespace
  labels:
    app: appName
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: appName-sc-ebs
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

Storage class:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: appName-sc-ebs
  namespace: appName-namespace
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
parameters:
  type: gp3
  zone: us-west-2a,us-west-2b
allowVolumeExpansion: true
reclaimPolicy: Retain
allowedTopologies:
- matchLabelExpressions:
  - key: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
    values:
    - us-west-2a    
    - us-west-2b
```

From what I saw in documentation and other sources **volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer** and **allowedTopologies** should help with this problem, but I have no luck.

Anyone had a similar experience? Or maybe this whole approach is wrong...Using EFS is not an option due to cost.

EDIT:
changed provisioner: **kubernetes.io/aws-ebs** to **ebs.csi.aws.com** and now it works. Still not as I expected, but similar.
When pod is moved to another AZ and PVC is bound to an EBS on the initial AZ, the pod is moved back eventually to the initial one.
Is similar to a StatefulSet right now.

I would still love if someone has experience with this situation and can share.

Answer (score 0):

In AWS, EBS volumes are bound to a single AZ (Availability Zone).
If you wish to migrate your pod to another AZ, I would suggest taking EBS snapshot and restoring it in the desired AZ. Then, you can configure the PVC and attach it to your workload, and it will be able to deploy in the new AZ.

Note that **allowedTopologies** define constraints for new PVs provisioned from that storage class, so after provisioning they are tied to a specific AZ.

**References:**

- AWS Docs: "The volume and instance must be in the same Availability Zone" [AWS EBS DOC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-volumes.html)

Comment: hi, thanks for reply.
The thing is that, from what I understood from docs, the AWS CSI diver would create a new EBS to be bound to PVC when the pod is moved to another AZ. 
From my tests this doesn't happen.

Comment: Form my knowledge - It won't, I was able to do it by migrating it manually using EBS snapshot, then creating a new EBS volume from that snapshot and attaching the PVC to that PV and your k8s workload. 
Can you share those docs?